# How to set Finder to show all files in search including hidden and Library files?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

When I unistall an application I want to check for all remaining files on computer. Searching them with Finder doesn't show any protected file, for instance from Library, and also hidden files are never included in search. Can this be controlled or changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the System files and File visibility attributes to the filter bar:

[image]

Files that start with a period are still excluded though.

This makes Finder show hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

[mdfind](https://superuser.com/questions/51122/how-to-search-with-spotlight-more-effectively/412090#412090) includes system files by default, but it doesn't include hidden files unless you specify kMDItemFSInvisible=1.

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName=.bash_profile&&(kMDItemFSInvisible=1||kMDItemFSInvisible=0)'
```

Comment: Any idea how to include applications' package contents?

Comment: Why the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Still does not work to find any hidden (dot) files

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use the free ShowAllFiles app which adds an icon to the bar at the top of the screen. Clicking the icon will toggle hidden files and optionally relaunch Finder to auto refresh.

[showallfiles.com](http://showallfiles.com)

Disclosure: I made this app.