# Safari Autofill "Other Forms" is not working

Tags: safari, preferences, auto-complete

I complete forms on a particular website regularly. I used to be prompted (I cannot remember when this stopped, but it was after updating Safari - now 15.6) with previous entries in each field via a dropdown box (these were not generated by the site).

For eg. If in a particular field I'd previously (on different occasions) entered: 1234, 1235, 1236 & 1237 then as soon as I started typing 1 in that field a dropdown box would open with all these as suggestions to choose from. This would include complete sentences.
This no longer occurs.

I've spent much time searching for solutions after trying the obvious: turning off autofill/other forms, restarting Safari and turning it back on again to no avail.

I cannot even find out where the list of forms that have saved autofill data is kept (so I can delete it in the hope that it gets reinstated)...?

Is there a way to force information entered on a web page form to be saved?

If anyone can help me, it will save me an incredible amount of time over the rest of my life?

Comment: It's unfortunately not a structure you can go play in - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198287/how-to-edit-safari-form-values

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, but I don't want to play in it or change specifics like the questioner wanted in the link you reference. I just want it to work again...? Any suggestions for how to accomplish this are welcome...

Comment: Then your alternative is to throw it out & see if it starts over, properly.

Comment: I deleted Form Values, emptied the Bin, rebooted, reopened Safari, used a website that had previously showed in the list accessed via the 'edit' button next to 'Other Forms' in Safari Preferences: this did not result in 'Form Values' being recreated! All suggestions welcomed...?

Comment: Hello!

Please can someone help me? This is really something that should be working and surely there's someone out there who knows how to get it working again...?

Answer (score 0):

Other Forms data is generated by you once you enable this feature in Safari.

The [data store is encrypted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/198287/5472) and [hidden in your user library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84666/5472), so you can do a few things.

1. Delete it and then start entering data in this web site and others to recreate the data.
2. Try to [decrypt a copy of this file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359937/5472) so you can re-enter the previous data again by hand, sequentially in safari while browsing the appropriate web sites.
3. Contact the operator of that website if your browser no longer inputs data there the same way as the past.

The third item is most often the reason, the developers changed the code that makes the field and now safari doesn’t classify it the same manner as before. Not that the safari function has changed or broken.

If you can’t get this to work from many sites - possibly an Apple support call would be productive. The first thing Apple should suggest is to make a new user account to be sure your database and preferences didn’t get out of sync by intention or by error.